# Giving non-administrators ability to use a changed PATH

Tags: windows, powershell, path, registry

The PowerShell code below changes the `PATH` variable successfully when it is called from within a PowerShell instance that is being run **as administrator**.  And a Windows CMD command prompt this is also running **as administrator** can also use the updated `PATH`.  But the newly updated `PATH` is **NOT AVAILABLE** to normal-user-privileged instances of PowerShell or the Windows CMD command prompt.

> What specific changes need to be made to the PowerShell code below so that the updated `$newPath` value of the `PATH` variable is available to all command prompts and PowerShell instances?

```
    $newpath = "$oldpath;$pathItem"
    Write-Host "newpath is: $newpath"
    #Set the new version as the replacement PATH permanently, but not within this session
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $newPath
    #Set the new version as the replacement PATH within this session
    $env:path = $newPath
```

Separately, when I try to run the above code as a non-administrative user in PowerShell, the following line of code throws a permissions error and fails:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $newPath
```

Comment: Processes inherit their environment when they are created.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unprivileged place you can set a machine-level environment variable, aside from relaxing the permissions on that registry key (you really shouldn't do this).

You would either need to set the variable as a user-level environment variable:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( 'VARIABLE_NAME', 'VALUE', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User )
```

or if you only care about the environment variable being used within PowerShell, you could consider updating one of the [PowerShell profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6#the-profile-files) to set a process-level environment variable:

```
$env:VARIABLE_NAME = 'VALUE'
```

The latter technique has two implications:

1. You still need to be privileged to modify the profiles under `$PSHOME`.
2. The process level variable will only be available in PowerShell sessions, and only if `powershell.exe` is not invoked with the `-NoProfile` parameter.

Comment: The version for setting the variable as a user-level environment variable. ...  How can I set it for the current user, whomever that current user might be (as a variable)?  This needs to work for anyone who runs this code on their machine.

Comment: You can make sure to set the environment variable in your script at the user level as shown in the answer. Unless I'm missing something here.